# PDF viewer with subpixel rendering

Tags: pdf, text, antialiasing

Is there any PDF viewer (besides Adobe Reader) which is able to render text with sub-pixel anti-aliasing? Or perhaps there is an option somewhere which enables it?

I tried MuPDF and Document Viewer/Evince to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox can render PDF via pdf.js - and uses excellent subpixel rendering.

Comment: That's true, thanks for the suggestion. But it is also very slow and even worse, consumes so much memory, it is almost impossible to zoom or view complex PDFs. Compared to, say, MuPDF which is super light. I guess I have to wait until [Implement tiling of canvas into smaller pieces](https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/issues/6419).